# What is the safest, quickest and most efficient way to transfer then merge several photo libraries from an old iMac to a new iMac?

Tags: imac, data-transfer, photos.app

I have an iMac(2009) that has approx. 250gb of photos in 2 or 3 libraries. I would like to transfer all of the photos to my new iMac(2107) and then merge them into one master library. Due to the fact that the old iMac is running a High Sierra beta and the new one is not, I cannot simply use Migration Assistant. What is the safest, quickest and most efficient way to transfer then merge the photo libraries from the 2009 to the 2017 iMac?

I have seen posts suggesting the use of PowerPhotos. I have the app but I need to put the libraries somewhere that PP can access them. The iMacs are connected by ethernet cable an on same network...but PP is not giving me option to simply import the libraries through the app. Alternatively, what I have done is started to import all of the photos to a folder my Dropbox account. Once they are in there I can import them. I am looking for some suggestions on a better/faster/more efficient way. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need any album/folder/project structure to remain intact or is a migration of the photos themselves enough? What application are the photos kept in, Photos, Aperture, something else?

Comment: one library is an IPhotos library. The other a Photos library. I would prefer that albums/folders/projects transfer....I also use Google Photos, which didn't transfer albums, etc...but their search functionality is so dam good that I never have any issues finding photos (by person/place/thing/date) that I am seeking.

Comment: @patrix No suggestions?